# Select an element of a list based on another variable?

Tags: r, list, date

I'd like to select an element of the built in R list, `month.abb` (which is a list of month abbreviations) based on a date column in a dataframe.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

my_data <- tibble(date = c("2018-12-12", "2017-11-10")) %>%
 mutate(date = as_date(date))

my_data %>%
 mutate(month = month.abb[[month(date)]])
```

I get the following error though:
`Error in muate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: attempt to select more than one element in a vectorIndex`.  I guess this means I'm tryingto select an element of a list with an entire vector and what I probably need is some mapping function like `lapply()`, though I'm not sure how I would implement it in this case.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the difference of `[[` and `[`.  According to `?Extract`,

> The most important distinction between [, [[ and $ is that the [ can select more than one element whereas the other two select a single element.

Here, we have more than one element as index

```
my_data %>% 
    mutate(month = month.abb[month(date)])
```

---

The error is not specific to `tidyverse`.  It is basically the indexing

```
c(2, 4, 7, 5)[[1:3]]
```

> Error in c(2, 4, 7, 5)[[1:3]] :    attempt to select more than one
>   element in vectorIndex

```
c(2, 4, 7, 5)[1:3]
#[1] 2 4 7
```