# Select value from column based on condition in other column to compute value in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this dataframe in R

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
   year    med
  <dbl>  <dbl>
1  2004 16753.
2  2021 28868.
```

which can be created with this dput:

```
structure(list(year = c(2004, 2021), med = c(16752.7, 28868.05
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

I now want to compute the ratio of the `med` value for the latest year with the `med` value of the lowest year. The years can vary across many of these dataframes, so it should be more generic.

I thought this way might work:

```
df %>%
     mutate(ratio = med[[year == max(year)]] / med[[year == min(year)]]) %>%
```

but it does not. If I use a single `[`, instead of a double bracket `[[` it works:

```
a %>%
      mutate(ratio = med[year == max(year)] / med[year == min(year)]) %>%
```

I am a bit confused as I thought I would select a single element of the `med` column using the `[[` syntax and a boolean value (`year == max(year)`)

Comment: thanks:) but shouldn't `year==max(year)`make sure that it is a single index?

Comment: @RitchieSacramento write an answer, i'll upvote it! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Inside of `dplyr::mutate()`, when referencing a column it is essentially a vector, which is why the single bracket works. But you can instead use `dplyr::first()` and `dplyr::last()` to reference the appropriate values.

```
df |>
  dplyr::arrange(year) |>
  dplyr::mutate(
    ratio = dplyr::last(med) / dplyr::first(med)
  )
```

The above code could be extended to calculate the ratio for each group if you had another column in your data that specified a group that the information pertained to.

Comment: Thank you very much! I still do not understand fully, why I can't use the double brackets. If it is a vector, I should be able to index it with double brackets shouldn't I?

Comment: The `[[` operator can only be used to select a single element, where `year == max(year)` is a vector of TRUE/FALSE with a length of two and in order to use the double square brackets it can only have a length of one. See this [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54752154/select-an-element-of-a-list-based-on-another-variable) for a bit more explanation.